# Python Win32API screenshot wrong colors

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, win32gui

Im using the win32 api to try to take screenshots. Everything works fine, but the colors are somewhat distorted.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con

def window_capture():

    h = 1080
    w = 1920

    hwnd = None
    
    wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
    cDC = dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
    dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, w, h)
    cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
    cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (w, h), dcObj, (0, 0), win32con.SRCCOPY)
    # dataBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(cDC, 'debug.bmp')
    signedIntsArray = dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
    # img = np.array(signedIntsArray).astype(dtype='uint8')
    img = np.frombuffer(signedIntsArray, dtype='int8')
    img.shape = (h,w,4)

    # Free Resources
    dcObj.DeleteDC()
    cDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, wDC)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())

    #img = img[...,:3]

    img = np.ascontiguousarray(img)

    return img



while True:

    # Take screenshot
    screenshot = window_capture()  # fastest

    cv.imshow("Computer Vision", screenshot)

    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

What I wanted is something like the left image. But instead I got the right image, with all those color deformations. Anyone can tell whats going on? I have seen other people doing the same and everything went fine.

[here are the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXvpo.jpg)

Comment: When replacing `img = np.frombuffer(signedIntsArray, dtype='int8')` with `img = np.frombuffer(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')`, everything looks fine in my machine.

Comment: Thats it. I forgot to add the 'u'. Just to see the damage a stupid missing char does.